# Using if condition in WinSCP script file to check if a file exist

Tags: batch-file, ssis, scripting, ftp, winscp

In an SSIS package using the execute process task I am executing a script file which is WinSCP scripting to connect to an FTP site via WinSCP.

I am able to use the basics like `get`, `put`, `open` commands in WinSCP.

But there is a scenario where I want to check if a file exist on an FTP site and if it does I pull the file else I pull a different file WinSCP.

However it seems that the moment I put `if` it just fails the script like it cannot read that syntax.

Does `if` statement not exist for WinSCP script files?

I was using this link for reference in building the if statement:  https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence#scripting

This is the WinSCP script file code I have.

```
# Automatically abort script on errors
option batch abort
# Disable overwrite confirmations that conflict with the previous
option confirm off
# Connect
open FTP
# Remote FTP Folder
cd SSISFTP
# get file attributes
stat FILEONE.txt
# conditional statement
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error
# Get FILEONE File
get FILEONE.txt
# Disconnect
close
# Exit WinSCP
exit /b 0

:error
get FILETWO.txt
# Disconnect
close
# Exit WinSCP
exit /b 1`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [article you refer to](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence#scripting) does not contain the code that you are attempting.

The article shows that you need to create a Windows batch file (`.bat`) and use it first to run WinSCP to determine if a file exists. And then do something based on that finding. In your case, you will need to run WinSCP again to do the actual download. Something like this (not tested):

```
@echo off

set SESSION=mysession 
set REMOTE_DIR=/home/user
set REMOTE_FILE=test.txt
winscp.com /command ^
    "open %SESSION%" ^
    "stat %REMOTE_DIR%/%REMOTE_FILE%" ^
    "exit"
 
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
    echo File %REMOTE_FILE% exists, will download it
) else (
    set REMOTE_FILE=other.txt
    echo Error or file %REMOTE_FILE% not exists, will download %REMOTE_FILE%
)

winscp.com /command ^
    "open %SESSION%" ^
    "get %REMOTE_DIR%/%REMOTE_FILE%" ^
    "exit"
```

---

Though from SSIS, I'd recommend you to instead use Script Task with C# (or other) code and WinSCP .NET assembly. See [Using WinSCP .NET Assembly from SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis).

In the code, you can use [`Session.FileExists`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_fileexists) method to determine if a file exists. This is [also covered in the article that you refer to](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence#library) (although for PowerShell).